# Parsing JSON missing quotes on name

Tags: php, json

Is it possible to parse JSON when the name is missing double quotes? The JSON is coming from google and it's in the form of:

```
{e:"Data",b:"Data",f:"Data"}
```

I can't inform Google their JSON is invalid, because it's probably invalid for a reason for their proprietary system. When using json_decode() it returns NULL.

Is their any libraries that are able to parse JSON in this format?

Answer (score 6):

JSON is a subset of YAML, so any valid JSON syntax is valid YAML syntax. YAML, however, doesn't require quotes around property names, so a YAML parser will cope with this content.

My preferred YAML parser is the [Symfony YAML component](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml), which you could use as follows:

```
<?php

include('yaml/lib/sfYaml.php');

var_dump(sfYaml::load('{e:"Data",b:"Data",f:"Data"}'));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["e"]=>
  string(4) "Data"
  ["b"]=>
  string(4) "Data"
  ["f"]=>
  string(4) "Data"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

// Serialize native Javascript object to JSON. To quote the key names. key=>'key'

```
function fix_json( $j ){
  $j = trim( $j );
  $j = ltrim( $j, '(' );
  $j = rtrim( $j, ')' );
  $a = preg_split('#(?<!\\\\)\"#', $j );
  for( $i=0; $i < count( $a ); $i+=2 ){
    $s = $a[$i];
    $s = preg_replace('#([^\s\[\]\{\}\:\,]+):#', '"\1":', $s );
    $a[$i] = $s;
  }
  //var_dump($a);
  $j = implode( '"', $a );
  //var_dump( $j );
  return $j;
}
```

Example :

```
 $json = '{e:"Data",b:"Data",f:"Data"}';
 echo fix_json($json);
```

Output :

```
{"e":"Data","b":"Data","f":"Data"}
```

Comment: Great idea, but it will compose a malformed json if value is an url: `{url:'http://www.example.com'}`, can you provide an updated version of the regex to pass this test? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this looks invalid. You might want to think about adding quotes using a piece of custom php code.

Comment: I agree. A simple preg_replace should be enough.