# Parse page in to array in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I am retrieving events from a CCTV system which is returning data in the following format,

```
[ 
{ alarmimage : '060429.0', timestamp : '1370099686.721', date : '2013-06-01', time : '16:14:46', events : 'VM' }, 
{ alarmimage : '060428.0', timestamp : '1370097952.081', date : '2013-06-01', time : '15:45:52', events : 'VM' }, 
{ alarmimage : '060427.0', timestamp : '1370097946.972', date : '2013-06-01', time : '15:45:46', events : 'VM' }, 
{ alarmimage : '060426.0', timestamp : '1370084199.546', date : '2013-06-01', time : '11:56:39', events : 'VM' }, 
{ alarmimage : '060425.0', timestamp : '1370083407.462', date : '2013-06-01', time : '11:43:27', events : 'VM' } 
]
```

I am simply using `get_data()` to return the above, what is the most effective way to loop through each of these values to display as a list of events/ images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the key names you'll get from your CCTV system are not in quotes, the string is not a valid JSON string. You won't be able to parse it with `json_decode` without performing some ugly string modification.

When searching for an alternative, I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6250894/1560865

The answer recommends to use the fact that JSON is a subset of YAML. Since YAML is a bit less strict about the quotes, you'll therefore should be able to parse your string with a YAML parser.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the issue, it does make far more sense now. I will pursue the solutions here. Thanks Hauke

Answer (score 1):

Thats a format called json (javascript object notation).

You can parse it very simple with `json_decode()`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: It might also be worth taking a look at [json.org](http://json.org) for reference.

Comment: Thank you, I had used json_decode() initially but realise now that there are differences in the outputs which lead me to believe it wasn't the correct usage, I have tried to explain this below. Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) with something like this:

```
<?php

$encdata = getTheData(); // your method to get the string
$data = json_decode($encdata);
foreach($data => $row)
{ 
    // access the row members like this:
    // $row->alarmimage
    // $row->timestamp 
    // $row->date
    // ...
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it, I think I had complicated the issue with the behavior of the camera, some of the cameras seem to output without the quotation marks, is there a way of handling this with the same loop? the output that the above loop seems to work on is like this  [
  {
    "alarmimage": "111941.0",
    "date": "2013-06-02",
    "events": "TT",
    "eventlist": [
      { "name": "TT", "eventid": "TT", "type": "TIM" }],
    "time": "12:01:01",
    "timestamp": "1370170861.648"
  }, the format as original posted without the quotation marks does not work? Many thanks

Comment: Hmm, its  changing the quotation marks around the values but I think I need them around the key's aswell to be valid? Its leaving me with this [ { alarmimage : "060646.0", timestamp : "1370184797.838",  Many thanks

Comment: I reverted my answer to its original state. My edit actually didn't help to fix your problem. I'll add another answer to this question.